# how to send the device token to server in ios6?

Tags: iphone, ios6, devicetoken

I want to send the device token to server in my application. I am using following method to retrieve the device token.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
     NSLog(@"deviceToken: %@", deviceToken);
}
```

but not worked in ios6. How can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you written this line

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

inside this function,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

It should work in iOS 6 if you have done this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Urbanariship you need to clean up the deviceToken before sending it back via a NSURLConnection PUT to the urbanairship servers.

```
NSString *deviceToken = [[_deviceToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""];
    deviceToken = [deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] ;
    deviceToken = [deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
```

Other wise you can send using NSURequest/ NSURLConnection

Hope this will help you out. or just let us know if you want code for Request and Connection as well.

Comment: /*[[UAirship shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken]*/ Register device token is deprecated in libUairship-1.3.0... What should i do? Please help if you know.